# Reuse output variables from previous job

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to run 'publish-storybook' job conditionally, based on the variable from the previous job. Complete action file:

```yaml
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

concurrency: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.2.0
        with:
          node-version-file: ".nvmrc"
          cache: "yarn"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Create Release Pull Request or Publish to npm
        id: changesets
        uses: changesets/action@v1
        with:
          publish: yarn release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_KEY }}

      - name: Send a message if a publish happens
        if: steps.changesets.outputs.published == 'true'
        run: echo "A new version of ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} was published!"

  publish-storybook:
    name: Publish Storybook
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: release
    if: needs.release.outputs.published == 'true'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.2.0
        with:
          node-version-file: ".nvmrc"
          cache: "yarn"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Storybook deploy
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.actor }}:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: yarn storybook:deploy
```

The message `A new version of ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} was published!` gets printed out in the output but a subsequent job that has a condition: `if: needs.release.outputs.published == 'true'` doesn't start, so there must be something wrong with this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only defining `steps.outputs` and not `job.outputs`.

```
jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      published: ${{ steps.changesets.outputs.published }}
    steps:

[... no further changes]
```

See also:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs